# SQLiteDatabase Android Performance Question

Tags: android

From performance point of view, regardless of other constraints:

> What is the cost of opening a SQLiteDatabase in the whole application lifecycle?
>
> ---
>
> Is it worth the effort to open/close everytime needed (and maintaining state)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open the database once => One open/close
2. Open the database multiple times => Multiple open/close

In 1) and 2), the memory cost is the same while the database is open. So 2) is obviously more expensive with this very reduced set of hypothesis.

Comment: but there must be some cost for the database being open the whole process cycle?

Answer (score 1):

If you use [`SQLiteOpenHelper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html), it will cache your database object meaning it will be opened only once and closed only once. You can then use [`getReadableDatabase()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getReadableDatabase%28%29) or [`getWriteableDatabase()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getWritableDatabase%28%29) wherever and whenever is convenient because you will be using the cached database.

`SQLiteOpenHelper` also makes it really easy to create, open, and upgrade (and with API 11, downgrade too) your database and is the Google recommended way of working with SQLite.